# How to add and update mesh in blender python game engine

Tags: python, game-engine

I am trying to build a simple game in blender, however, I have run into a problem. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(enter_editmode=True)
mesh = bpy.data.objects['Cube.001']
me = mesh.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
for x in bm.faces:
    x.select = False
face = bm.faces[3]
face.select = True
print(face)
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='ONLY_FACE')
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Cube.001 never gets shown until after the game exits back to the editor. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to BlenderStackExchange,

For me using the latest UPBGE 0.3 release I oddly get the opposite problem;
<kbd>Cube.001</kbd> is disappearing after runtime because Blender is automatically deleting as it wasn't originally created in Blender's viewport.

For me, unselecting the <kbd>Undo at Exit</kbd> setting prevented Blender from removing the newly created object after runtime had exited solved my issue, perhaps it'll work for you as well.

[image]

Also, the reason your newly created mesh may not show for you at runtime may be because you need to convert your mesh to a BGE object. Dynamically created objects are only Blender objects. You can convert Blender objects to BGE objects with the following Python function:

```
KX_Scene.convertBlenderObject(object)
```

Comment: OK first, thanks for replying.  Now I dont know how to get to the window your snapshot shows and I cant for the life of me figure out what module I need to import to use KX_Scene.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: btw Im using blender 2.79

Comment: BPY doesn't work in legacy versions (e.g 2.7x) at runtime.

Only UPBGE 0.3 allows it to work properly at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For the discontinued BGE in previous version of Blender (< v2.80), the BPY API is not associated with the BGE API. Any manipulation of mesh data has to be done through the use of methods and properties provided in BGE classes like `bge.types.KX_MeshProxy`, `bge.types.KX_PolyProxy`, and`bge.types.KX_VertexProxy`.

***You cannot change the topology of a mesh at runtime,*** meaning that deletion, modification, or creation of face, edges, or vertices are not supported outside changing simple attributes like position. You will either have to implement a workaround, recompile Blender with that functionality, or switch to something like UPBGE that allows for use of the BPY API at runtime.